# How to see which part of the code is running in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

When you run a python script from terminal and before it completes running of you control + c  it, it gives a traceback where the code was currently running. Is it possible to see which part of a code is running without terminating it.

Answer (score 1):

in pycharm, you can debug by selecting code areas that you want to work, and by pressing next and next, you'll see how does program running it, without terminating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in PyCharm using the debugging facility. It allows you to step through your code line by line, running each line as you pass it. You can see what variables have been assigned etc. Very helpful for debugging!

See here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html